# How could I open my content provider to all applications within an android devices?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I was trying to create a content provider serving to all Apps in system; kept getting security permission error when ran other Apps to read.

Could anyone help to show me the sample of how to compose read permission in `Manifest`, because I cannot access developer.android.com even by VPN in PRC...shame...thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

To quote the developer docs:

> Content Provider Permissions
>   A provider's application can specify permissions that other applications must have in order to access the provider's data. These permissions ensure that the user knows what data an application will try to access. Based on the provider's requirements, other applications request the permissions they need in order to access the provider. End users see the requested permissions when they install the application.
>
> If a provider's application doesn't specify any permissions, then other applications have no access to the provider's data. However, components in the provider's application always have full read and write access, regardless of the specified permissions.

So you would need to declare a permission for the content provider in your manifest, such as:

```
  <permission android:name="com.your.app.permission.READ_MY_PROVIDER"
    android:label="@string/read_permission"
    android:description="@string/read_permission_description"
    android:protectionLevel="normal" />
```

As a child of the `<application>` element. The protection level should be `normal` if you want all apps to be able to access it, or `signature` if it should only be accessible by apps you have signed with the same key.

And add that permission to the provider like so:

```
    <provider
      ...
      android:readPermission="com.your.app.permission.READ_MY_PROVIDER"
      ... />
```

Then, request the same permission in the other apps, and they will be able to access your content provider:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.your.app.permission.READ_MY_PROVIDER">
```

Comment: "normal" permissions doesn't work if other apps are signed with different certs.